# How to set up external Infinispan for Keycloak?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, infinispan, keycloak

Keycloak can run its own embedded Infinispan.

But how do you configure keycloak to use an externeal Infinispan system?

Comment: What do you mean by 'external' system, connecting to standalone Infinispan Server using Hot Rod/REST protocols? And why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, question is how to connect to a standalone Infinispan Server. Why? Perhaps other systems want to use it, too...

Comment: @yogiginger were you able to achieve this ?

Comment: The keycloak team recently wrote a blog post about this topic, it contains an example setup for infinispan and keycloak: http://blog.keycloak.org/2017/09/cross-datacenter-support-in-keycloak.html

Comment: URL for the blog post has changed: https://www.keycloak.org/2017/09/cross-datacenter-support-in-keycloak.html